# Searching if a list exists in my python dictionary and append to the associated key

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python and any help will be greatly appreciated. I need to search through a dictionary to confirm if a list exists, if it does, I need to append it as an additional value to the associated key. Here is what I have written:

```
    _, p = scipy.stats.ks_2samp(k[i],buffer[j])
    if p > alpha:
        for key, value in cluster.iteritems():
            if value == buffer[j]:
                cluster[key].append(i)
```

But is get this error"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()".

Can someone help me please. The cluster in the code is a dictionary whose values are lists.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `value == buffer[j]` returns an array of Booleans. You should not use in an if statement like that. As the error-message suggests you can use one of

```
if (value == buffer[j]).all() ## true if all elements are equal
if (value == buffer[j]).any() ## true if any of the elements are equal
```

to avoid this error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. It did help